# Error on Creating Fault message- unknown JAXBContext Implementation: class com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, websphere

Throwing error when creating custom Fault error message in SoapHandler.
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.databindingexception:unknown JAXBContext Implementation: class com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl

I am using java8,Jaxws-spring jar and Application deployed in WebSphere

Code Snippet-

```
private void generateSOAPErrMessage(SOAPMessage msg, String reason,HttpServletResponse res) {
        try {
            SOAPBody soapBody = msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();
            SOAPFault soapFault = soapBody.addFault();
            soapFault.setFaultString(reason);
            throw new SOAPFaultException(soapFault);
        }catch (SOAPException e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the third-party JAX-WS implementation doesn't like the JAXB implementation provided by WebSphere. Out of curiosity, have you turned of the JAX-WS implementation provided by WebSphere. Should be documented here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PK96989